# Proper way to save python dictionaries and retrieve them at a later stage

Tags: python, oop, pickle

following an earlier question I asked here ([Most appropriate way to combine features of a class to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393190/most-appropriate-way-to-combine-features-of-a-class-to-another)) I got an answer that I finally grown to understand. In short what I intend to now is have a bunch of dictionaries, each dictionary will look somewhat like this:

```
{ "url": "http://....", "parser": SomeParserClass }
```

though more properties might be added later but will include either strings or some other classes.
Now my question is: what's the best way to save these objects?

I thought up of 3 solutions, not sure which one is the best and if there are any other more acceptable solutions.

1. Use pickle, while it seems efficient to use it would make editing any of these dictionaries a pain, since it's saved in binary format.
2. Save each dictionary in a separate module and import these modules dynamically from a single directory, each module would either have a function inside it to return the dictionary or a specially crafted variable name to hold it so I could call it from my loading code. This seems the easier the edit but doesn't sound very efficient or pythonic
3. Use some sort of database like MongoDB or Riak to save these objects, my problem with this one is either editing which is doable but doesn't sound like fun and the fact that the former 2 are equipped with means to correctly save my parser class inside the dictionary, I have no idea how these databases serialize or 'pickle' such objects.

As you see my main concerns are how easy would it be to edit them, the efficiency of saving and retrieving the data (though not a huge concern since I only have a couple of hundreds of these) and the correctness of the solution.

So, any thoughts?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: You might consider json.  It supports python dictionaries. They can also be easily edited.

Comment: There's probably a lot of detail you haven't told/can't tell us that will inform your decision. Are the keys always the same type? Is your data essentially finite? Then use JSON. If not, type conversions may cause key collisions. Pickle is particularly useful for saving hashable, executable objects, and it's clever about recursive references, but it can also be a vulnerability. "What is the best way to serialize Python data?" is not actually a subjective question, but it is highly sensitive to the nature of the data you're serializing.

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON.  It supports python dictionaries and can be easily edited.

Comment: Note that Python dictionaries do not map perfectly to JSON. In particular try `json.loads( json.dumps( {15: "a", "15": "b"} ) )`.

Comment: Also, you're going to have to define special handling for the classes in the `parser` values.  JSON is more or less a subset of Python dictionaries; JSON can be represented as dictionaries, but not all dictionaries can be transparently represented as JSON.

Comment: Well thanks but again what will be the best way to save the data? Granted I now have json formatted objects, I am still stuck with the best way to save them as in my original question.

Comment: Once you have JSON, you can write it to whatever storage format you want.  File, simple database, whatever.  It's just a string at that point.

Comment: While, like you noted so are python dictionaries, but I am still unsure whether it would be best to save them in a database or in separate files and just read those files as text, or load them with the json loader, or as python modules? I guess my question is more on where to save the data instead of in what format but I will look into the json thing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use separate files or Python modules.  This basically sounds like static configuration data, which should live in one or at most a very few files (or if you have a whole lot of it that you need to curate, a database).  Unless you set any of these up dynamically at run time, you don't need anything complicated.  A yaml, JSON, or other formatted config file would work fine.  It's not even unheard of to use a straight Python module this way (Django configs and setup.py to a lesser extent come to mind).

Comment: To answer more directly, unless you have specific system requirements on how or where to store data, it's more a question of personal style and consistency of your software than any sort of best practice.  If you already have config data in a file, use that or another file.  If you have some in a database, use an existing or new table.  Just choose one and stick with it for your entire application.

Comment: Well thanks for clearing that, it was really helpful. I guess the reason I wanted to use python modules is that those dictionaries hold references to another class, the parser one. I didn't want to have to pickle / serialize that object everytime since most urls share the same parser. The reason for multiple files was that I have a few hundred of those and I didn't want to just stick them all in one large file. As of now if I'm saving the data as text (JSON basically), my best option regarding the parser is to just save the class name of the parser and load it dynamically in runtime?

Comment: Maybe you could save the strings that define the parser and then rebuild it as needed?  A possibility.  Is the parser the main "object-code" thing you need to store?  (Versus text or integers).

Comment: I actually don't need to store the parsers, they are just classes with some functionality, only about 5 of them, each dictionary represents a url, parser combo with some additional data to be passed to the parser, so I just need to save that combo data somewhere, the parsers are just in their respective modules. That's why I wanted to avoid pickling / jsoning the parsers themselves and thought about saving just the parser class name in text form and just load it and initialize it dynamically as I load the dictionaries I saved. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't select the proper parse using a text name.

Comment: I'm not saying I can't rather I'm asking if that's considered OK, to save a class name and then initialize it dynamically as in: `getattr(MyParserModule, parser_name_loaded_from_json)()`, cause that's what I meant, did you mean anything different?

Comment: I don't see any problem with it.  An important aspect of code is that it works for you.  Lots of stuff has no standard way of implementation, so do something you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html). It's built on top of `pickle` and let's you serialize objects and associate them to string keys.

Because it is based on `dbm`, it will only access key/values as you need them. So if you only need to access a few items from a large dictionary, `shelve` may be a better choice than `json`, which has to load the entire JSON file into a dictionary first.